# In what contexts can I use the terms "year-on-year"/"year-over-year"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Specifically, can I use "year-on-year" or "year-over-year" to describe a change in periods shorter than a year across different years (such differences in the year to date).

If, for example, I had 100,000 in revenue from January to September 2020, and I had 150,000 in revenue from January to September 2021, could I say:

"After the third quarter, revenue for the year to date grew 50% year-over-year."

Comment: Given the details of the example, "In the third quarter, revenue grew 50% year-over-year." would potentially be misleading.

Comment: “January to September” isn’t the third quarter.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I edited the example a bit, but my question is more on specifically if "year-on-year" can be used to describe specific portions of the year from one year to the next.